# Can't append the array value returned from asp.net webservice in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

I am calling a webservice from ajax call. The Webservice is returning all the values fine. Since one of the properties is of datetime i am using this Js function to parse the date.

```js
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
  var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
  var results = pattern.exec(value);
  var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
  return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
  // return (dt.getFullYear() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) +"/" + dt.getDate());
}
```

**Here i am calling the webservice**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#ShowInGridButton').on('click',
    function() {
      var accountNumberId = $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val();
      var fromDate = $("input[name*='FromDateControl']").val();
      var toDate = $("input[name*='ToDateControl']").val();
      var url = "/WebMethods/Deposit.asmx/GetDepositAccountStatement";
      var d = {
        accountNumberId: accountNumberId,
        fromDate: fromDate,
        toDate: toDate
      };
      var jqXhr = ajaxPost(url, d);
      jqXhr.done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data) {
          var div = $('#CfDataTable').empty();
          div.append(
            $("<tr class='success'><th>Tran Date</th><th>Value Date</th><th>Statement Reference</th><th>Check No.</th><th>Collector</th><th>Debit</th><th>Credit</th><th>Balance</th></tr>"));

          $(data.d).each(function(index, item) {

            div.append(
              $("<tr>")
              .append($("<td>").html(ToJavaScriptDate(item.TranDate)))
              .append($("<td>").html(ToJavaScriptDate(item.ValueDate)))
              // .append($("<td>").html(item.TranDate))
              // .append($("<td>").html(item.ValueDate))
              .append($("<td>").html(item.StatementReference))
              .append($("<td>").html(item.CheckNumber))
              .append($("<td>").html(item.Collector))
              .append($("<td>").html(item.Debit))
              .append($("<td>").html(item.Credit))
              .append($("<td>").html(item.Balance)));
          });
        }
      }).fail(function() {
        console.log('Data Retrieve failed.');
      });
    });
});
```

**XML output**

```html
<ArrayOfDepositAccountStatementView xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://Everest.Net.Web.WebMethods/">
  <DepositAccountStatementView>
    <TranId>13018256</TranId>
    <TranDate>2016-01-14T00:00:00</TranDate>
    <ValueDate>2016-01-14T00:00:00</ValueDate>
    <Collector>Office</Collector>
    <Debit xsi:nil="true" />
    <Credit>11000</Credit>
    <Balance>11000</Balance>
  </DepositAccountStatementView>
  <DepositAccountStatementView>
    <TranId>23601</TranId>
    <TranDate>2016-02-04T00:00:00</TranDate>
    <ValueDate>2016-02-04T00:00:00</ValueDate>
    <StatementReference>Collected by Krishna Pokhrel</StatementReference>
    <Collector>Krishna Pokhrel</Collector>
    <Debit>0</Debit>
    <Credit>1000</Credit>
    <Balance>12000</Balance>
    <CheckNumber/>
  </DepositAccountStatementView>
  <DepositAccountStatementView>
    <TranId>69273</TranId>
    <TranDate>2016-03-01T00:00:00</TranDate>
    <ValueDate>2016-03-01T00:00:00</ValueDate>
    <StatementReference>Collected by Krishna Pokhrel</StatementReference>
    <Collector>Krishna Pokhrel</Collector>
    <Debit>0</Debit>
    <Credit>1000</Credit>
    <Balance>13000</Balance>
    <CheckNumber/>
  </DepositAccountStatementView>
  <DepositAccountStatementView>
    <TranId>118061</TranId>
    <TranDate>2016-04-01T00:00:00</TranDate>
    <ValueDate>2016-04-01T00:00:00</ValueDate>
    <StatementReference>Collected by Krishna Pokhrel</StatementReference>
    <Collector>Krishna Pokhrel</Collector>
    <Debit>0</Debit>
    <Credit>1000</Credit>
    <Balance>14000</Balance>
    <CheckNumber/>
  </DepositAccountStatementView>
  <DepositAccountStatementView>
    <TranId>180233</TranId>
    <TranDate>2016-05-10T00:00:00</TranDate>
    <ValueDate>2016-05-10T00:00:00</ValueDate>
    <StatementReference>Collected by Krishna Pokhrel</StatementReference>
    <Collector>Krishna Pokhrel</Collector>
    <Debit>0</Debit>
    <Credit>1000</Credit>
    <Balance>15000</Balance>
    <CheckNumber/>
  </DepositAccountStatementView>
  <DepositAccountStatementView>
    <TranId>230251</TranId>
    <TranDate>2016-06-08T00:00:00</TranDate>
    <ValueDate>2016-06-08T00:00:00</ValueDate>
    <StatementReference>Collected by Krishna Pokhrel</StatementReference>
    <Collector>Krishna Pokhrel</Collector>
    <Debit>0</Debit>
    <Credit>1000</Credit>
    <Balance>16000</Balance>
    <CheckNumber/>
  </DepositAccountStatementView>
  <DepositAccountStatementView>
    <TranId xsi:nil="true" />
    <TranDate xsi:nil="true" />
    <ValueDate xsi:nil="true" />
    <StatementReference>Total</StatementReference>
    <Debit>0</Debit>
    <Credit>16000</Credit>
    <Balance xsi:nil="true" />
  </DepositAccountStatementView>
</ArrayOfDepositAccountStatementView>
```

Everything is working fine. But when one of the row has null values for TranDate
and ValueDate null, I can't see any data in my appended div.

If I don't use the above JS dateparser and simply append like item.TranDate I get all the rows with tranDate as TranDate: `"/Date(1460398500000)/"`

What is wrong here?

I tried `JSON.stringyfy(item.TranDate)` but reached nowhere.

In my console I can see the data as

> {__type: "Everest.Net.Common.Deposit.Views.DepositAccountStatementView", TranId: null, TranDate: null, ValueDate: null, StatementReference: "Total"

but this does not get appended in the div.

Comment: Thanks sir..will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this..problem was with my ToJavaScriptDate function.I had to check a null value before calling the function.

```js
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
     if(value !== null
        && value !== undefined
)
     {
                var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
                var results = pattern.exec(value);
                var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
                return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
                // return (dt.getFullYear() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) +"/" + dt.getDate());
     }
     else
     {
          return '';
     }
}
```